# How to fix dropped frames from a slow database connection?

Tags: java, android

```html
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                button2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
                button2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                Log.d("email", email);
                email = emailView.getText().toString();
                Log.d("email2", email);
                password = passwordView.getText().toString();
                connection.start();
                try {
                    connection.join();
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }


                Log.d("00", "00");
                Log.d("11", "11");
                if (!validate()) {
                    onFailed();
                    clearForm((ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.lin));
                    progressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    button2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                } else {
                    screenSize();
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

I have an android app that I have been making for work which makes two calls to two different databases.  One database is on site and is our and is super fast while the other connection is to an old database system off site.  I have used Async and now I am using java threads (I find them easier to work with and alot more useful).  I just want to know if there is a way to stop these dropped frames when connecting to the database when the user logs in because this creates a lag in when the log in button is submitted and then skips the progress spinner.  The lag is around 2 second and normally drops around 300 frames.

Comment: You are waiting for the thread to finish. Don't do this, it blocks the UI thread and makes the multi-threading useless. Instead handle the result asynchronously.

Comment: You might want to explain how this login screen fits in your app workflow. If its settings type screen, you could do a toast when the credentials fail or if it is a slide show type gating don't have the 'next' button/screen appear until verified.

Comment: @MorrisonChang yes I will sorry.  I am using this login screen and when the first call returns it will return with a 1 or 0 and 1 is pass while 0 is fail.  This is based on email and password.  When this is returned then it will go to validate which will see the 1 or 0 and if it is a one then it should start a spinner and make the submit the button invisible.  If it is a 0 then it will make a toast saying that the login has failed.  The second database connection returns with a long sting and I split it and put it in an array to pass to the next page.

Comment: @Henry So the reason I need to do this is because if I do not wait for it then my validate will always be wrong. I tried with async but I needed to do the same as this. I am trying to get the work off of the main thread

Comment: Please explain why you can't call validate after calling connection both on a separate thread.

Comment: It is not necessary to do all this validate stuff in the `onClick` handler. Let it finish as soon as possible (just after the connection thread is started) and do the validation when the thread is ready.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that `connection` in the following is a `Thread`.

```
            connection.start();
            try {
                connection.join();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

If so, then the problem is clear.  When you call `join()` you block the UI thread.  That is what causes the "lagging".  If you want to avoid lagging and frame loss, you *must not* cause the UI thread to block.

The solution is something like this:

1. The listener should launch the thread (or whatever), put the UI into a "waiting to validate" state, and return.
2. The thread should establish the database connection, validate the credentials, then use `runOnUiThread` to take the UI out of the "waiting to validate" state.
3. If the user clicks the button while in "waiting to validate", ignore it.

The background thread could update the UI to indicate progress.  And there needs to be some indication to the user that the validation step has passed or failed.